# How do I make an image fade across on page transition?

Tags: jquery, css

Sort of new to programming, and working on my company's site right now.. I'm attempting to achieve something similar to the page transitions on http://www.la-grange.ca this site. I'd like to have a similar affect to their page transition with the wood.. but I can't figure out how to do it or exactly how I should be explaining it... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
    $(".transitionbar").removeClass('hidden');
    $(".transitionbar").css({height: '400'}).animate({marginTop: '-840'}, 1000);
});
```

Here's something similar, after a quick play around, its just a start on what you're trying to achive.

http://jsfiddle.net/1c885e3f/

You'd need to script a reset function for the item if you're planning to use Ajax to display page content, otherwise this should work when running separate pages.

Here's a somewhat crude example of what a reset could look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/1c885e3f/1/

Comment: if you work with this method and need any more help, just comment and I'll see if I can rework elements and make it easier for your individual use etc.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. Now I just have to incorporate into a page transition and I'll be good to go! Thanks!!